# Looping through a nested table type PLSQL

Tags: oracle, for-loop, plsql, collections

I have a record type:

```
TYPE SOME_RECTYPE IS RECORD
(attr1          ATTR1_TBLTYPE,
 attr2          ATTR2_TBLTYPE,
 rec_dtl                RECDTL_TBLTYPE
);
```

where `ATTR1_TBLTYPE` and `ATTR2_TBLTYPE` are tables of a DB column, something like:

`TYPE ATTR1_TBLTYPE IS TABLE OF SOME_TABLE.ATTR1%TYPE INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;`

and `RECDTL_TBLTYPE` is a table of another record type:

```
TYPE SOMEOTHER_RECTYPE IS RECORD
(attr3          ATTR3_TBLTYPE,
attr4          ATTR4_TBLTYPE
);
```

How do I retrieve the values of `attr3` and `attr4`?

I tried looping like this:

```
FOR i IN attr1.FIRST..attr1.LAST LOOP
   dbms_output.put_line(attr1(i));
   dbms_output.put_line(attr2(i));
   FOR j in rec_dtl(i).attr3.FIRST..rec_dtl(i).attr3.LAST LOOP
      dbms_output.put_line(attr3(i));
   END LOOP;
END LOOP;
```

It is giving me `ORA-01403: no data found error` 
It is because of the indexing : `rec_dtl(i).attr3`

So, how to iterate the loop to fetch the values of `attr3` and `attr4`?

Answer (score 1):

You are using associative arrays and there is no guarantee that they will not be sparse so you should use `assoc_array.FIRST` to get the first index and then `assoc_array.NEXT( index )` in a loop to iterate through indexes.

```sql
DECLARE
  TYPE ATTR1_TBLTYPE IS TABLE OF SOME_TABLE.ATTR1%TYPE INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
  TYPE ATTR2_TBLTYPE IS TABLE OF SOME_TABLE.ATTR2%TYPE INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
  TYPE ATTR3_TBLTYPE IS TABLE OF SOME_TABLE.ATTR3%TYPE INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
  TYPE ATTR4_TBLTYPE IS TABLE OF SOME_TABLE.ATTR4%TYPE INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

  TYPE RECDTL_TBLTYPE IS RECORD(
    attr3          ATTR3_TBLTYPE,
    attr4          ATTR4_TBLTYPE
  );

  TYPE SOME_RECTYPE IS RECORD(
    attr1          ATTR1_TBLTYPE,
    attr2          ATTR2_TBLTYPE,
    rec_dtl        RECDTL_TBLTYPE
  );

  value SOME_RECTYPE;
  i     BINARY_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  -- Sample Data
  value.attr1(1) := 'Hello';
  value.attr1(3) := 'World';
  value.attr2(-9) := 0;
  value.rec_dtl.attr3(1) := TRUNC(SYSDATE);
  value.rec_dtl.attr3(2) := DATE '1970-01-01';
  value.rec_dtl.attr4(0) := EMPTY_CLOB();

  -- Loop Through attr1:
  i := value.attr1.FIRST;
  WHILE i IS NOT NULL LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'value.attr1(' || i || ') = ' || value.attr1(i) );
    i := value.attr1.NEXT(i);
  END LOOP;

  -- Loop through rec_dtl.attr3:
  i := value.rec_dtl.attr3.FIRST;
  WHILE i IS NOT NULL LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'value.rec_dtl.attr3(' || i || ') = ' || value.rec_dtl.attr3(i) );
    i := value.rec_dtl.attr3.NEXT(i);
  END LOOP;

END;
/
```

Outputs:

> ```
> value.attr1(1) = Hello
> value.attr1(3) = World
> value.rec_dtl.attr3(1) = 22-AUG-19
> value.rec_dtl.attr3(2) = 01-JAN-70
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2b4d072c3218af6a1541fc154f67e529)*

Answer (score 0):

`TYPE ATTR1_TBLTYPE IS TABLE OF xxxx INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER` 
is not the same as
`TYPE ATTR2_TBLTYPE IS TABLE OF xxxx`

For the 2-nd you are sure that your collection is dens and you can iterate it using `for..loop`
For 1st you should use approach with key word next.

```
declare 
type type1 is table of varchar2(4000) index by binary_integer;
v1 type1;
idx binary_integer;
begin 

v1(1) := 'a';
v1(2) := 'b';
v1(5) := 'c';

v1(-10) := 'Collection is allways sorted by index';
idx := v1.first;
while (idx is not null) loop
dbms_output.put_line(v1(idx)||'- is value of index '||idx);
idx := v1.next(idx);
end loop;
end;
```